# Perform operation on all objects of object's properties

Tags: c#

Is it possible to express something like this in C#:

```
List<Object> l = null;
foreach (var property in this)            // Current Object
{
    l = property as List<Object>;

    if(null != l) l.Clear();
}
```

Meaning to enumerate all properties and in case the property points to an object of type `T`, then perform operation `foo()` on the object it refers to

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, why don't you know youre properties at compile time?  You could do it with reflection but this sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: @JensHorstmann: So what is the use of your comment?

Comment: @TimSchmelter : True, but there are so many properties and the class will be modified many times, that (re-)initialisation is at best done this way

Comment: if `this` is an `IEnumerable` then yes it would work, but quite possibly not in the way you are hoping.. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse : since it is not possible to initialize an auto-implemented property and it will be a huge pain to keep track of all properties added/ removed during development, I want the object-(re-)initialisation done this way (saves lines of code, is better readable, ...)

Comment: @Benj: if there are so many properties that you consider using a reflection approach to get them it's certainly better to refactor your class. If all properties are of the same type or mean similar things use a collection like `List<int>` or `Dictionary<string, int>`(where the string could represent your property name/type and the value it's value).

Comment: @Benj - I would argue the opposite too though, by always resetting every property you could quite well break someone elses code (and potentially less performant).. If you need to "reset" a class, then do so by just making the reference reference a new object. What is the *exact* problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using reflection:

```
foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propVal = property.GetValue(this) as List<Object>;
    if (propVal != null)
    {
        propVal.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get Property like this:

```
    public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string identifier)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(identifier);
    }
```

and with this you get all Properties:

```
    public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties();
    }
```

then you can use foreach on it and get the value:

```
    var properties = this.GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        property.GetValue(this, null);
    }
```

You only need to implement this methods in your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Object> MyList { get; set; }
    public MyClass myField;

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.MyList = new List<object>();
    }

    public void ClearLists()
    {
        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.FullName == typeof(List<Object>).FullName)
            {
                (prop.GetValue(this) as List<Object>).Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public void FieldAction(Type fieldType, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (var field in this.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            if (field.FieldType.Equals(fieldType))
            {
                var val = field.GetValue(this);
                val.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(val, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        c.MyList.Add(new Object());
        c.ClearLists();
        Console.WriteLine(c.MyList.Count.ToString()); // 0

        c.myField = new MyClass();
        c.myField.MyList.Add(new Object());

        c.FieldAction(typeof(MyClass), "ClearLists");
        Console.WriteLine(c.myField.MyList.Count.ToString()); // 0
    }
}
```